# Absolute element won't scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using position `absolute` will make my dynamic element doesn't go together with other elements when I scroll up/down.
But if I will use `relative` it will work. But I need the position absolute to not mess the sizes of other elements (example: I need to maintain the height of nodes 1-3).

HTML

```
<ul id="container">
  <li id="1">node 1</li>
  <li id="2">node 2</li>
  <li id="3">node 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
  padding: 50px;
}

ul{
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;  
}
```

JS

```
var template = document.createElement('div');
template.style.height = "100px";
template.style.width = "100px";
template.style.border = "1px solid blue";
template.style.position="absolute"; // I NEED THIS AS I DON'T WANT THE ELEMENT TO PUSH OTHER ELEMENTS AFTER IT

//template.style.position="absolute"; //THIS FIX THE ISSUE BUT THIS WILL MOVE OTHER ELEMENTS

var el1 = document.getElementById('1');
el1.append(template);
```

Here's the fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nw2x0k9r/6/)

Comment: Position absolute will be relative to closest relative parent. Which in your case it the body tag. Does making the `#container { position: relative; }` solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `position: relative` to the parent tag `<li>`:

```
li {
    padding: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

...will you get the expected result?

```js
var template = document.createElement('div');
  template.style.height = "100px";
  template.style.width = "100px";
  template.style.border = "1px solid blue";
  template.style.position="absolute";

var el1 = document.getElementById('1');
  el1.append(template);
```

```css
li{
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
}


ul{
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;  
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li id="1">node 1</li>
  <li id="2">node 2</li>
  <li id="3">node 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It will push other nodes down, I need to maintain the space between nodes. Here's what I got if we add relative on parent : https://jsfiddle.net/neg985h6/1/

Comment: @JunM, Why are you adding `position: relative;` for `div` - `template.style.position="relative";`? This must be done for the `li` tag, and then the distance will be the same between the `li` tags.

Comment: My apologies, I removed it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o9Ljhesn/1/

Comment: @JunM, But you removed absolute positioning. What for? Do it in this way - `template.style.position="absolute";`

Comment: thanks for the help, it works now. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d6konjeg/

Comment: @JunM, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the **position absolute is work inside the Parent who have position relative**. so please insure your absolute element vary inside the relative element.